# Взять из описание конкретное значение

Tags: c#

Есть переменная куда входит описание:

```
Инициатор: 
Подразделение:
Должность: 
Телефоны: 
Уч. запись: admin
```

Как мне вывести данные которые находятся после "Уч. запись:"?

Comment: Если "Уч. запись:" всегда последняя, то split строку по ":" и взять последний элемент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text = @"Инициатор: 
Подразделение:
Должность: 
Телефоны: 
Уч. запись: admin";

var new_text = text.Split(':')[text.Split(':').Length - 1];
```

> admin

> Если "Уч. запись:" всегда последняя, то split строку по ":" и взять последний элемент - [Виктор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/325344/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)

upd: `text.Substring(text.LastIndexOf(':') + 1)` - [aepot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373567/aepot)

Comment: `text.Substring(text.LastIndexOf(':') + 1)`